# SMW Page Forms Extension: Display checkbox/radiobutton items vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

Dear Semantic MediaWiki Community,

when using checkboxes or radiobuttons in Semantic MediaWiki's Page Forms extension, the default display behaviour of such items is horizontally, i.e., they are displayed next to each other in the same line.

My question is:
Is there an easy way (e.g., via setting a parameter in the {{{field|...}}} declaration) that allows the items to be displayed below each other (**=vertically** instead of horizontally), i.e., **each item in a separate line**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an easy way (e.g., via setting a parameter ...)

No. Custom Javascript is the way. Add some JS code in your mediawiki `common.js` that add a line break after each Page Forms element you want to separate. You just have to inspect the generated html to find structure and specific classes of the elements.

For instance, a radiobutton generated with Page Forms is llike:

```
<span id="span_13" class="radioButtonSpan mandatoryFieldSpan pfShowIfChecked">
    <label class="radioButtonItem" for="input_12"><input name="Invoice[paystat]" type="radio" value="Received" checked="checked" id="input_12" tabindex="12"> Received</label>
    <label class="radioButtonItem" for="input_13"><input name="Invoice[paystat]" type="radio" value="Paid with petty cash" id="input_13" tabindex="13"> Paid with petty cash</label>
</span>
```

Here your JS code would be to add a `<br>` after each `label` belonging to a `span` of class `radioButtonSpan`

So, appart from the specific classes of `Page Forms` needed to select the elements, this is a pure JavaScript operation, for which you will find countless tutorials and examples.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on that...?
I never heard of common.js in conjunction with page forms / SMW / etc.